# How to Convert a Map<String, List<String>> to Map<String, String> in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `map` like

```
key= ["a1", "a2", "a3"] 
value = [["a1.value1", "a1.value2"],["a2.value1", "a2.value2"]]
```

the resulting Map should be like

```
key = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
value = ["a1.value1, a1.value2", "a2.value1, a2.value2"]
```

How can we use `Collectors.joining` as an intermediate step ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question...  are you trying to map multiple values to the same key in a Map, i.e. have multiple Map entries per a specific key? In a Java Map, the keys are a set, meaning no single key value can repeat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can we use Collectors.joining as an intermediate step ?

You mean, in the collecting phase...

Yes, you can:

```
Map<String, String> result = 
        source.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                      e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(joining(", "))));
```

*but*, better to use `String.join`:

```
Map<String, String> result = 
     source.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> String.join(", ", e.getValue())));
```

or none stream variant:

```
Map<String, String> resultSet = new HashMap<>();
source.forEach((k, v) -> resultSet.put(k, String.join(",", v)));
```